What is the best way to get all token holders and their balances by mint address?
There is a way to get token accounts by mint address using
https://spl.solana.com/token#finding-all-token-accounts-for-a-specific-mint
But unfortunately it only returns token accounts without balances, i need iterate to get all balances.
Wondering is there a better way to do this ?
Note : I am looking for solution purely based on RPC endpoint, not some 3rd party API

Thanks for accepting my answer! Make sure to also click the button for the bounty, as otherwise it will expire and then no one gets it :)

Done thanks for answering this

Here you go, this will return all non-zero balances:
const conn = new Connection('<INSERT RPC HERE>');
const MINT = new PublicKey('<INSERT MINT HERE>');
const TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID = new PublicKey('TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA');
const TOKEN_ACC_SIZE = 165;
const accs = await conn.getProgramAccounts(TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, { dataSlice: { offset: 64, length: 8 }, filters: [{ dataSize: TOKEN_ACC_SIZE }, { memcmp: { offset: 0, bytes: MINT.toBase58() } }] });

// Filter out zero balance accounts
const nonZero = accs.filter((acc) => !acc.account.data.equals(Buffer.from([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])));

const firstHundred = nonZero.slice(0, 100);
for (const acc of firstHundred) {
    const accData = acc.account.data;
    const balance = accData.readBigUInt64LE();
    console.log(`Balance of ${acc.pubkey.toBase58()} is ${balance}`);
}

We use the getProgramAccounts RPC method here, which returns all accounts owned by a specified program. Since we care about token accounts here (and all token accounts are owned by the token program) we start with this.
This would return us every token account (and any other account we owned by the token program) in existence though, so we need to filter:

Filter to only accounts with length 165, which is the fixed length that token accounts have. This way we get rid of accounts that are owned by the token program but aren't token accounts.
Filter to only accounts where the first 32 bytes equal the mint we care about. If we look at the format of token accounts, we can see the first 32 bytes always specify the mint.

Note that getProgramAccounts isn't supported by the free Solana RPC for some reason (even though it's part of the official spec, weird...) but I just tested this with Quicknode and Helius and for those (and I assume pretty much every other RPC provider too) it works fine.
Edit: I just realized you only care about the balances. If we consult the spec again, we see that's stored in byte 64-72. So we specify we only want those bytes using the dataSlice filter. Then we can simply convert that to a u64 like  in the loop below. I only did the first 100 in my example because accs was something like 200k long for the token I was testing with and I didn't want to spam my terminal, but it of course also works with the full array of accounts.
